# Which airport in Amsterdam is AMS

Tags: netherlands, amsterdam, ams, vueling

I am going to Amsterdam on Vueling. On the boarding pass it is written **AMS** as destination, but I don't know which airport that is. I was planning some trips using http://www.ns.nl/en and that website is giving me two options when writing *airport*

[image]

I thought that Schiphol is the only airport in Amsterdam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AMS is **Schiphol airport** in Amsterdam. It's called [Amsterdam Airport Schiphol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Airport_Schiphol). Search engines usually let you search either by the airport name directly, or by the city.
The airport name is sometimes given as one, sometimes as the other, most of the time as a combination.
Rail planners make this a mess more often than air search sites, as those mostly give the three letters AMS, with the name.

This is to make things easier for people when searching, since some airport names are quite complicated, for example "Bandaranaike International Airport" in Colombo, Sri Lanka. People can search by that, or by "Colombo". Note, when searching by the city name, and if the city has more than one airport, the search engine will list all flights available for any of the airports in that city.

Comment: thanks, please do you know how to pronounce Schiphol? (is it shifoul) ?

Comment: @user2059935 Skipol, [check this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=km-BwxjbIDA) to listen to the pronunciation.

Comment: The above linked pronunciation will get you there. It the best people who don't speak Dutch usually can make of it. For the proper Dutch pronunciation see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IC8iL7UCtQ

Comment: For those who do not like to follow links, if you pronounce it as the English words Ship Hole you come near enough that all Dutch will not mind and you get close to the most used English pronounciation, And you also get very close to the meaning of the word(s) making up the name of the airport.

Comment: @Willeke in my opinion "skip hole" is better than "ship hole" (think *school*).

Comment: Not in my experience. And just dropping the C from the word makes it more logical to remember for most people. The SK is what people try to get closer to the Dutch SG sound, but it is not as near as English people think it is.

Comment: @AVee thanks for the link, though the second sound is hard, it is like from spanish sound, i can do it separately but not in a word :)

Comment: @Willeke as long as they don't say "ski pole," which I once heard on a travel show on the radio and it took me about 10 minutes to realize what they were talking about.  But I'm also thinking of Schermerhorn St. in Brooklyn ("skermerhorn"). There are also many words from Dutch *sch-* words that became *sk-* words in English, such as *skipper.*

Comment: @phoog, I have seen that happen, more so even in Swedish, but that does not mean that the pronounciation is closer to the local one.

Comment: @Willeke but I doubt that "ski pole" means something in Swedish as it does in English.  I really thought they were talking about a place named after ski poles.  As to whether "ship" or "skip" is closer to "schip," I suppose it depends on where the Dutch speaker is from.  Largely my preference for "skip" may be related to my allergy to British sportscasters pronouncing Dutch or Flemish names as if they were German (recently, De Bruyne -> De Bräune).  But it's also easier to teach people how to pronounce "schip" correctly if you start from "skip" and then change the k into a fricative.

Comment: Note that the _train station_ is called "Schiphol Airport". In English, without Amsterdam.

Answer (score 6):

The two items you see in the selection list are alternate names for the same station.  Try asking for the schedule for trips from *Amsterdam Airport* to *Schiphol Airport* and you'll see what I mean.  The site is unable to provide them.

Alternately, compare the schedules for trips between one airport and another station to those for trips between the other airport and the same station.  You will see that they are identical.

The airport is listed twice so people who don't know the name "Schiphol" will also be able to find it.

Comment: I recognise NS website colours and I wonder, why they didn't combine them. Probably because space is limited and that would a too long name "Amsterdam airport Schiphol"

Comment: @EugenMartynov I rather suspect that they did it so the hordes of clueless tourists who don't know that the airport's name is *Schiphol* can nonetheless find their train schedules when they search for *Amsterdam airport.*   The image shows a list that is more than twice as wide as it needs to be to fit the longer of the two names.